# How can i join 2 dataframes using a string column using get_dummies and count a repetitive word within a string

Tags: python, pandas

Hello i am trying to create a somewhat matrix view having the below example:

```
import pandas as pd
sales = [{'account': 'Jones,LLC', 'Jan': 150},
             {'account': 'Alpha,Co',  'Jan': 200},
             {'account': 'Blue,Inc',  'Jan': 50,}]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
sales2 = [{'account': 'Jones,LLC,Co,Jones'},
         {'account': 'Alpha,Co,Blue'},
         {'account': 'Blue,Inc',}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sales2)

df3=df.join(df2.account.str.get_dummies(sep=','))
df3.head()
```

If you look at the df2 you will see that the first row contains the string Jones two times and if you look at df3 you will see that column Jones has 1 in the first row and i am looking for counting it twice as it appears twice in first row of df2.

I get this (just showing the fraction of the DF which interests me)

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      account        |    Jones         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Jones,LLC      |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------
```

I want to get this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      account        |    Jones         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Jones,LLC      |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
*`pd.value_counts`*

```
df.join(df2.account.str.split(',').apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int))

   Jan    account  Alpha  Blue  Co  Inc  Jones  LLC
0  150  Jones,LLC      0     0   1    0      2    1
1  200   Alpha,Co      1     1   1    0      0    0
2   50   Blue,Inc      0     1   0    1      0    0
```

**Option 2**
*`np.bincount`*
This is far more involved, less transparent, method using a combination of `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`.  It is quicker!  But not as obvious.  This can also act as motivation to appreciate `pandas`' api.

```
rows = split(df2.account.values.astype(str), ',')
lens = [len(row) for row in rows.tolist()]
vals = np.concatenate(rows)
f, u = pd.factorize(vals)
n, m = len(lens), u.size
i = np.arange(n).repeat(lens)
counts = np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)

df.join(pd.DataFrame(counts, df2.index, u))

   Jan    account  Jones  LLC  Co  Alpha  Blue  Inc
0  150  Jones,LLC      2    1   1      0     0    0
1  200   Alpha,Co      0    0   1      1     1    0
2   50   Blue,Inc      0    0   0      0     1    1
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit
rows = split(df2.account.values.astype(str), ',')
lens = [len(row) for row in rows.tolist()]
vals = np.concatenate(rows)
f, u = pd.factorize(vals)
n, m = len(lens), u.size
i = np.arange(n).repeat(lens)
counts = np.bincount(i * m + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)

df.join(pd.DataFrame(counts, df2.index, u))

1000 loops, best of 3: 685 µs per loop

%timeit df.join(df2.account.str.split(',').apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int))

100 loops, best of 3: 2.34 ms per loop

%timeit df.join(df2.account.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x))).fillna(0).astype(int))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `Series.str.get_dummies` is supposed to be used in this manner, in the sense that it will returns binary indicators -- and not counts -- for each variable. The `pd.get_dummies` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas.get_dummies) has a few examples that demonstrate this behavior.

There may be another solution to getting the count of each substring, but one quick way to do it is with `Counter` from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter
df2.account.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x)))
#    Alpha  Blue   Co  Inc  Jones  LLC
# 0    NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN    2.0  1.0
# 1    1.0   1.0  1.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
# 2    NaN   1.0  NaN  1.0    NaN  NaN
# add .fillna(0) to the end of the expression of you don't want NaN values
```

This can be joined exactly as you indicated:

```
df.join(df2.account.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x))))
#    Jan    account  Alpha  Blue   Co  Inc  Jones  LLC
# 0  150  Jones,LLC    NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN    2.0  1.0
# 1  200   Alpha,Co    1.0   1.0  1.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
# 2   50   Blue,Inc    NaN   1.0  NaN  1.0    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is a good answer!  PlusOne.  I'd add a `fillna(0).astype(int)` after the `apply`.